# Eigenvalues of self-adjoint/orthogonal endomorphism $\pm 1$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be simultaniously self-adjoint and orthogonal. Show that $\lambda = \pm1$ for all eigenvalues of $f$. Does this also apply for self-adjoint (respectively orthogonal or normal) endomorphisms?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is orthogonal then it preserves the norm so if $x$ is an eigenvector of $f$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ then
$$||f(x)||=|\lambda||\cdot||x||=||x||$$
hence 
$$|\lambda|=1$$
but if moreover $f$ is symmetric then their eigenvalues are real so $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: yes, f is symmetric and there is also a no-degenerated bilinearform <,>. is there a solution without use of the norm? why did you not use that f is self- adjoint?

Comment: $f$ is self-adjoint is equivalent to say $f$ is symmetric.

Comment: could I also do: $<f(v),f(w)> = <\lambda v,\lambda w> = |\lambda| <v,w> \Rightarrow |\lambda| = 1$(because orthogonal by asumption) for v,w eigenvectors?

Comment: @user149868 you should have 
$$
\langle f(v),f(w) \rangle = 
\langle \lambda v,\lambda w \rangle = 
|\lambda|^{\color{red}2} \langle v,w \rangle
$$
But otherwise, that is correct.

Comment: We'll try this again! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- $f$ is orthogonal $\implies$ $|\lambda| = 1$ for all eigenvalues of $f$
- $f$ is self-adjoint $\implies$ $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ for all eigenvalues of $f$

The conclusion follows.